# .NET Bug - Threading.Timer affects Parallel.For performance

Tags: .net, multithreading, timer

I have a VB.NET WinForms application which makes use of sequential Parallel.For statements.

After adding a Threading.Timer, the Parallel.For loops slow to a crawl and the amount of kernel time jumps to nearly 80 percent.

The two are not related in my code (i.e. neither is run by the other), nor do they share any code or data.

Removing the timer fixes the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?  What is the best method for working around this behaviour (would rather not create a WinForms Timer but will if I have to)?

This is the code executed by the Timer:

```
Public Sub Tick()
  IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\test.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString())
End Sub
```

This is the timer creation statement:

```
tmrFile = New Threading.Timer(AddressOf Tick, Nothing, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Interesting.. Can you post some simple code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Simple in this context is perhaps not very simple.  The parallel fors are doing heavy memory copying and image resampling.  The threading timer is simply updating a file with the current date time.  If I get some time, I'll see if I can't make an example to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @ColorEyes, If you remove the Parallel.For loops, does just the timer-stuff keep your machine busy?

Comment: @Albin - If I comment out the Parallel.For loops, the program seems to run normally (albeit, no work gets done). So taking out either the loops or the timer makes the program run ok. Perhaps running the timer and the loops is thrashing the ThreadPool in some manner (provided they both use the thread pool).

Comment: @ColorEyes .. and if you keep the timer, but don't do anything useful in it? How often does the timer run?

Comment: @ColorEyes also, I think what Albin meant is what if you remove the 'Parallel.' part of 'Parallel.For'? :)

Comment: @Robert Jeppesen - The timer runs once every minute.

Comment: @Robert Jeppesen - Keeping the timer and the parallel.fors and commenting out the line of code that the timer executes exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: @Albin - If you mean run the loop with a normal for and keep the timer, then yes the bad behaviour is still there (high kernel time slow running). Which, perhaps, then points to what is being executed in the for loop (two lines of code, both third party library calls.  However, AFAIK, those calls are not multi-threaded.)

Answer (score 1):

Is your timer signaling very often? If so, you might be getting overwhelmed in the number of threads being fired from the timer. There is a finite number of threads that can be running and if the Timer is taking too much time from signaling too often then the rest of your code is going to suffer.

Can you analyze what your timer is doing and share that information? How often it signals, any particularly rough code it's executing, if it is doing parallel tasks too, etc.

Comment: It signals once per minute. When it signals it write the current date and time to a file.  I have tried increasing this to 10 minutes, but the same behaviour exists.

Comment: How is it doing the writing to a file? Locking around the open, write, flush, close operation? Just hoping the write is complete before the next thread at the next signal? Does the code start slow when you use the timer or does it become slow over time?

Comment: If you are interested in those details the code is posted above.  However, it doesn't matter, because even with the code commented out, (i.e. an empty tick) the behaviour is still exhibited.

Comment: Looking at various documentation it appears the Timer uses ThreadPool threads. The documentation on Timer reveals this and discloses signals may still happen even after Dispose is called because of this. So, I'm wondering how many ThreadPool threads your Parallel.For statements are trying to use and how many your Timer is using. There are static methods on ThreadPool that can let you investigate this if you want. I'm wondering if you're over-allocated. Thread usage info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try taking it out of the thread pool! I threw together a simple timer class for you to try out (not production code, mind you). This class runs in a separate thread.

The class:

```
  public class ThreadedTimer : IDisposable
  {
     private readonly AutoResetEvent _isStopping = new AutoResetEvent(false);
     public ThreadedTimer(Action f, int interval)
     {
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
           while (!_isStopping.WaitOne(interval))
           {
              f();
           }
        });
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
        _isStopping.Set();
     }
  }
```

Start a timer:

```
var timer = new ThreadedTimer(() => Debug.WriteLine("Test"), 1000);
```

**Update:** 
Completely untested code in VB below

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class ThreadedTimer
    Implements IDisposable
    Private ReadOnly _isStopping As New AutoResetEvent(False)

    Public Sub New(ByVal f As Action, ByVal interval As Integer)
        Dim t As New Thread(Sub()
                                While Not _isStopping.WaitOne(interval)
                                    f()
                                End While
                            End Sub)
        t.IsBackground = True
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        _isStopping.[Set]()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code is so trivial and such an obvious solution that I had already implemented my own threaded timer. Besides, my question doesn't revolve around how to implement trivial solutions, it's why doesn't the Threading.Timer work with my code? That's the crux of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @ColorEyes Sorry it didn't help, but there no reason to be an a-hole about it. Kind of goes against the spirit of this site. How is anyone supposed to know what you consider 'an obvious solution'?